# Update nested state in redux without library

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability

Let's say, i have following state.

```
let state = {
        DirectoryMap :{
            root :{
                name : "root",
                nested : null
            },
                    ........
                        ........
        },
        currentDirectoryNode : null,
        currentDirectory : 'root'
    }
```

I want to update following:

- Nested value inside **root** object .
- Add **new object inside DirectoryMap** object.

Flattening structure is recommended but in this situation, i can't do it more due to some tradeoff.

I want to different ways i can perform above operation without mutating the original state. Also i don't wanna use any library like immutable.js etc. Vanilla JS or ES6/ES7 features would be better maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can do something like this,

```
let newState = jQuery.extend(true, {}, state);
```

Another way is this

```
newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Comment: Above operations involve deep copy of state which is not preferred way of updating state. Deep copying  the full state is also a very costly operation.